# d3.js drawing a line transform error

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, runtime-error

I'm new to d3.js, and I'm getting a `ReferenceError: x is not defined`.

I'm just trying to draw a line of points.

```
var points = svg.selectAll('.dots')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "dots");

points.selectAll('.dot')
            .data(function (d, index)
                {
                    var a = [];
                    d.values.forEach(function (values, i)
                    {
                        a.push({'x': values.x, 'y': values.y});
                    });
                    return a;
                })
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'dot')
            .attr("r", 2.5)
            .attr('fill', function (d, i)
            {
                return colors[i];
            })
            .attr("transform", function (d)
            {
                /* Line 268: Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined */
                return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
            }
        );
```

In a lot of internet samples, I see x() and y() being used in translate/transform when drawing stuff. What am I doing wrong? I even have other code samples using this x() and y() and they're not throwing errors. I can't figure out the difference or what I'm missing.

`d.x` is actually a date, and `d.y` is a number.

If I change Line 268 to:

```
  /* Removing x() and y() fixes the error: */
  /* d.index increments from 0 up; assume this exists */
  return "translate(" + d.index + "," + d.y + ")";
```

I get a perfectly working collection of points drawn (not a line actually, so not exactly what I need, but at least thousands of points show up and the data is being read correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Got it, silly me, you have to define `x` and `y`:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
                        .domain([
                            d3.min(activeData, function(d) { return d.x; }),
                            d3.max(activeData, function(d) { return d.x; })
                               ])
                        .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([
                             (d3.min(activeData, function(d) { return d.y; })),
                              d3.max(activeData, function(d) { return d.y; })
                                 ])
                         .range([height, 0]);
```